# What's the exact definition for convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I tried to solve the problem in Stein's **Real analysis**, 1ed, P94, Ex 21 (c), which asked to show that for any two measurable functions $f,g$ on $R^d$, the convolution of $f$ and $g$,  $$(f\ast g)(x)=\int_{R^d}f(x-y)g(y)dy$$ 
is well defined for a.e. $x$, i.e., $f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable on $R^d$ for a.e. $x$.

If $f,g$ are integrable, this will be easy conclusion of $(a)$ and $(b)$, but it seems form $(d)$, that the integrability of $f,g$ are not assumed here!

From wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Domain_of_definition
we know that $f\ast g$ is only defined for some classes of $f$ and  $g$, if $f,g$ are only measurable, I do suspect that the convolution is well defined.

Comment: The convolution is NOT well defined for all $f,g$ measurable. Choose $f,g$ such that $f(x-y)g(y)$ is not integrable for any $x$. E.g. $f(x)=1, g(x)=\sin(x)$ then clearly the convolution $f*g$ doesn't make sense for any $x$.

Comment: If $d>1$, then you would need multiple integrals.

Comment: @nullUser if we assume that there exist one (or some) point of $x$ such that $f\ast g$ is well defined for $x$, then can we say that $f\ast g$ are well defined a.e.?

Comment: @vanabel I have thought about it for a while and haven't come up with a proof or counterexample. The standard result on existence of convolutions (on $\mathbb{R}^d$) is called Young's inequality: If $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d), g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\frac1p + \frac1q = \frac1r + 1$ then $||f * g||_r \leq ||f||_p||g||_q$.